# Visual Studio 2013 Razor intellisense not recognizing the start of a lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, lambda, intellisense

I'm having a minor annoyance with VS 2013 when working in ASP.NET MVC Razor views. When typing something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.[PropertyName])`, as soon as I type the first <kbd>m</kbd>, intellisense pops up a drop down with `mbox` selected. Then when I press the space key it inserts `mbox` into my code. Is there anything I can do, besides turning off intellisense, so that I can type my code without having to dismiss the intellisense suggesetion? If I type `@Html.TextBoxFor()` first, and then go back and fill in the expression, I get the desired behavior, but that is no more convenient.

**Edit**

I don't have anything imported directly in this view. In the web.configs I have the following:

```
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="EPiServer.Shell.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="EPiServer.Framework.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html" />


    <add namespace="LGMVCWeb.ViewModels"/>

    <add namespace="LGMVCWeb.Models.Pages.OE"/>
    <add namespace="LGMVCWeb.ViewModels.Pages.OE"/>
    <add namespace="LGMVCWeb.ViewModels.Shared.OE"/>
```

Comment: I just press the Esc key to dismiss the intellisense menu.

Comment: @br4d That's the annoyance. Intellisense is failing at the point when it starts adding required keystrokes, IMO. I feel like it didn't used to do this too. Maybe in an older version of VS.

Comment: What are your references in the view? `using System;` and so on. Are there any unused references like whatever `mbox` uses? `System.Windows.Forms` or something like that.

Comment: Actually, I just tried again and it isnt doing it in my VS2013 but it is in VS2012 (with the default intellisense and editor settings). Have you installed the VS2013 updates and service packs? They may have already fixed this

Comment: @area28 see my edit. The same thing happens if I try to type "model" it is replaced with the intellisence selection "Model", referring to the view's Model.

Comment: @br4d I'm on v 12.0.31101.00 Update 4. It looks like there is now an update 5. Are you using that?

Comment: Yea I am using VS2013 Pro, same exact version as you. Maybe its this [Web Essentials extension](http://vswebessentials.com/) I am using?

Comment: Can you put the entire razor code to see the scenario, maybe you are losing the precise Model on your View

Comment: @Zinov this is the code for a new partial named _PartialPage1.cshtml. It has the same problem except it selects "MachineKey" instead of mBox. `@model System.Object 

@Html.TextBoxFor(m`